# Ranger: "zip error: Nothing to do!" - But it works in bash!

Tags: bash, zip, ranger

The following works:

```
$ zip -rj /the/absolute/path/tmp{.zip,}
```

It produced a file called tmp.zip, saving me the trouble to repeat the folder name as the name of the zip archive.

In my rifle.conf (ranger specific configuration file) I have:

```
!mime ^text, !ext xml|csv|tex|py|pl|rb|sh|php  = zip -rj "$@"{.zip,}
```

The "$@" translates to the path. This works fine, I make use of this a lot.
But when I try it, the error I get is:

```
zip error: Nothing to do! (/the/absolute/path/tmp{.zip,})
```

This has worked fine for me, too. It only stopped working after upgrading my OS and with it ranger. So there is likely something I am missing here.

```
$ ranger --version
ranger version: ranger 1.9.3
Python version: 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) [GCC 9.4.0]
Locale: en_US.UTF-8

$ cat /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Focal Fossa"
```

Comment: Inside the context of ranger, SHELL is /bin/bash. I found out by replacing the zip command with "echo $SHELL" and executing it within ranger.

Comment: The folder `/etc/upstream-release/` does not exist in Ubuntu 20.04. The answer posted by the OP makes it clear that the question is about Mint. I am voting to close this question as off topic.

Comment: @user68186 the root cause was ubuntu changing what sh points to, so this question is relevant for ubuntu users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was actually going on here is that ranger does a thing where if you execute files via shortcuts that things are executed as configured. In the case for shell this meant to do a call to "sh".

In previous versions of Linux Mint sh was just symlinked to bash, so the shortcut worked as "bash" in practice, even if if under the hood it was defined as sh.

But in the newer version, sh is no longer symlinked to bash, so you get a different shell and bash scripts throw weird errors, because they aren't executed as bash by the shortcut.

The fix is then to just update the config from sh to bash in the shortcut configuration (rifle.conf).

Comment: The question is about Ubuntu. Why is the answer about Mint? Mint is off topic here.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 `/bin/sh` is sym linked to `/bin/dash`.

Comment: @user68186 Mint is based on Ubuntu, so there's hardly any difference.

Comment: You may want to read the site help [what is off topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

The brace expansion which turns `foo{bar,cbs}baz` into `foobarbaz foocbsbaz` is done by `bash` when interpreting a command line. So the most probable explanation is that since the upgrade, `ranger` doesn't use `bash` for the execution of the command anymore.

Regrettably, `ranger` does not seem to document which shell it uses to interpret the commands in `rifle.conf` or whether that can be influenced. You may try to set the `SHELL` environment variable to `/bin/bash` in various places to see if it helps. If all else fails, write a wrapper shell script starting with `#!/bin/bash` around your command.

Comment: Sounds likely, yes. SHELL is /bin/bash for me.

Comment: For you, yes. But for ranger?

Comment: At least ranger reports that SHELL contains /bin/bash when I bind "echo $SHELL" inside ranger and execute it.

Comment: Interesting. In that case I really wonder why it doesn't use bash for parsing the command in rifle.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by not using zip, but apack instead.

This works:

```
!mime ^text, !ext xml|csv|tex|py|pl|rb|sh|php  = apack "$@".zip "$@"/
```

Comment: `zip -rj "$@".zip "$@"` would have worked as well. It was the braces abbreviation, not the command, that caused the problem.